# How can I write elastic search query for a piece of log in Kibana4

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I have a piece of log :

```
2016-02-10T08:51:07.000+00:00 [RTR] OUT app_url - 
[10/02/2016:08:51:07 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3418
"https://abcsomeootherurl" 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.2.3.4 Safari/537.36" 10.4.5.6.:44711 x_forwarded_for:"10.5.6.7" 
vcap_request_id:req_id response_time:0.021407606 app_id:some_id
```

I would like to form a elastic search query to be used in kibana4. How can I do that. Any lead would be highly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried regex pattern query?

Comment: No I dont have any idea about that. Can you help me with that. I was able to form queries in kibana3